# Soundcloud for Samsung Smart-TV

Tags: javascript, http, filesystems, soundcloud, samsung-smart-tv

We use the Soundcloud API , which allows sending information only between "http" or "https" protocols. The smart-TV, as far as we know, uses a kind of file system. Hence, the requests can't be sent to the Soundcloud server, and information can't be received from it, using the API.
Is there any way to host some kind of a private http server on the TV, and use it?
Or is there a different Soundcloud API module we can use?
Any other ideas are welcomed... 
Thanks!

Comment: This question is way too broad.  Do you have a more specific programming question we can help you answer.  How have you tried setting up a server already?

Answer (score 0):

Smart TV is capable of using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You can access Soundcloud HTTP API with it. However you may need to authentificate yourself somehow.

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out using Cross Domain Requests - `$.getJSON` etc.
 All of which is supported by the SoundCloud API.
*Thanks anyway!*